# Selenium select reports empty text selected option when there is a text in the selected option

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm using selenium and at some point of my tests I'm checking a select box selected item text.
Selenium reports empty text

```js
 new Select(selectElement).getFirstSelectedOption().getText()
```

But if I inspect element code:

```js
selectElement.getAttribute("innerHTML")
```

it reports somthing like

```html
<option selected='selected' value='op1'>op1</option>
<option value='op2'>op2</option>
<option value='op3'>op3</option>
```

One thing that might be causing this (I'm not sure) is the fact that selenium is not being able to scroll to the element (it is in some other scenarios)

Does anyone have an idea?

Thanks

Comment: You can try with `selectElement.findElement(By.xpath(".//option[@selected='selected']")).getText()`. Please check...

Comment: I've had similar issues in the past, this was due to the content of the Select element taking a while to render on the page. You may need to add in a wait.

Comment: Thanks for the input Vivek,
A odd as this may seem, it doesn't work either (I was also expecting it to work). Another thing I forgot to mention is that this works on my local machine, but it fails every time on jenkins server. This might be due to some race condition...

Comment: It's funny, I tried to wait for select options to display, but I got a timeout. I put a sleep of 2 seconds and it solved the issue. I guess Mark is right, but there is still some issue regarding my xpath. Any way if you (Mark) want to put an answer here I will mark it as correct. Thanks!